# Theorem on $C^r$ related charts

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

**PROBLEM:** Let $M$ be a set.  Let $\mathcal{A}=\{(U_{\alpha}, x_{\alpha})\}$ be an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued atlas of class $C^r$ on $M$.  Recall that an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued chart $(V,y)$ is compatible with $\mathcal{A}$ if $\mathcal{A}\cup \{(V,y)\}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued atlas of class $C^r$ on $M$.  Let each of the $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued charts $(V,y),(W,z)$ be compatible with $\mathcal{A}$.  Show that $(V,y)$ and $(W,z)$ are $C^r$-related charts.
**EDIT:**  Recall, a pair of charts are $C^r$-related if either $V\cap W=\emptyset$ or both $y(V\cap W)$ and $z(V\cap W)$ are open and $y\circ z^{-1}$ and $z\circ y^{-1}$ are $C^r$ maps (r times differentiable)

**Def: Let $M$ be a set.  A chart on $M$ is a bijection of a subset $U\subset M$ onto an open subset of some euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$**

Note that $M$ is just a set so we can't assume an induced topology.  Also, we can't assume that the charts are homeomorphisms.  When I attempted this problem I got it completely wrong because I assumed that the charts were homeomorphisms which is how some texts define a chart.

Comment: Well, what is your definition of a chart ?

Comment: @KonKan:  Oops!  Good point, fixed.

Comment: and when do you call two charts $\mathcal{C}^r$-related ?

Comment: @KonKan:  I added an explanation of $C^r$ related charts to the problem statement.

Comment: I am a little confused: Since you do not assume a topology on $M$, then how can you speak about open maps y,z mapping a subset of $M$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @KonKan: I agree, but this is how, Jeffrey M Lee's Manifolds and Differential Geometry text introduces the topic. I think I'm missing something subtle that he must point out somewhere but I've read this section of the text a couple of times and I can't pinpoint it

Comment: mm, I see... I also have the feeling that there is something missing here.

Comment: Check the Lemma 5.8 in Tu: "An Introduction to Manifolds" (2nd edition)

Comment: @IvicaSmolić:  It looks like Tu is working with a topological manifold (charts are homeomorphisms) in his solution.  Unfortunately I'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: In Lee's book, at the end of page 13, it is clarified how to put a topology on your set so that all charts turns out to be homeomorphism: he calls this "topology induced bu the atlas".